# How to query element from array with two conditions (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to query all document where groupData.users.userId = 'aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3' AND groupData.users.userId = 'pending'.

```
{
    "_id" : "Au2NH2iMwGfGtzqzH",
    "name" : "Toyota",
    "profileType" : "group",
    "groupData" : {
        "private" : false,
        "users" : [ 
            {
                "userId" : "9qcHtd4sRFZQpPaHD",
                "role" : "admin",
                "addedAt" : ISODate("2020-09-16T17:23:28.266Z")
            }, 
            {
                "userId" : "CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k",
                "role" : "member",
                "addedAt" : ISODate("2020-09-16T17:23:37.292Z")
            }, 
            {
                "userId" : "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3",
                "role" : "pending",
                "addedAt" : ISODate("2020-09-16T17:23:41.878Z")
            }, 
            {
                "userId" : "GoXMTJKCWSpRdyn7c",
                "role" : "member",
                "addedAt" : ISODate("2020-09-16T17:23:51.281Z")
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I trying the following:

```
            const profiles = Profiles.find({
                'groupData.users.userId': this.userId,
                'groupData.users.role': 'pending'
            }).fetch();
```

But it returns wrong profiles. Thank you!

Comment: See documentation topic: [Query an Array of Embedded Documents - Specify Multiple Conditions for Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/index.html#specify-multiple-conditions-for-array-of-documents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get with `elemMatch`. But you need to be aware of [Positional operator in projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)

```
db.collection.find({
  "groupData.users": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      userId: "aFHJBrKu54y5mWjY3",
      role: "pending"
    }
  }
},
{
  "groupData.users.$": 1
})
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IfL4Knj_On1)

Comment: @podeig you are welcome.. Why don't you consider to accept the answer which helps to people who seek this kind of problems

Comment: I am so sorry, Varman. I upvoted it but forgot to accept. Sorry :)